# Minimal gradle multi-project build including a global AST transformation

Tags: gradle, groovy, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to create a gradle project that applies a global AST transformation defined in project A to a class defined in project B. I've been following the instructions in this guide without success:

https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#transforms-global

My project structure is:

```
|- project-root
   |- settings.gradle
   |- A
      |-- build.gradle 
      |-- src
      └── main
          ├── groovy
          │   ├── gep
          │       └── WithLoggingASTTransformation.groovy
          └── resources
              └── META-INF
                  └── services
                      └── org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation
   |- B
      ├── build.gradle
      └── src
          └── main
              └── groovy
                  └── package1
                      └── Application.groovy
```

the settings.gradle for the root-project:

```
rootProject.name = 'test-global-ast'
include 'A'
include 'B'
```

The build.gradle for project A

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('org.apache.groovy:groovy-bom:4.0.5')
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy'
}
```

The build.gradle for project B

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'application'
}

mainClassName = 'project1.App'

configurations { astTransformation }

dependencies {
    implementation platform('org.apache.groovy:groovy-bom:4.0.5')
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy'
    astTransformation project(':A')
}

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile).configureEach {
    astTransformationClasspath.from(configurations.astTransformation)
}
```

B/gep/WithLoggingASTTransformation.groovy

```
package gep

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ASTNode
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ConstantExpression
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.VariableExpression
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.Statement
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilePhase
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit
import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation
import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.GroovyASTTransformation

@CompileStatic
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase= CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)
class WithLoggingASTTransformation implements ASTTransformation {

    @Override
    void visit(ASTNode[] nodes, SourceUnit sourceUnit) {
        def methods = sourceUnit.AST.methods
        methods.each { method ->
            def startMessage = createPrintlnAst("Starting $method.name")
            def endMessage = createPrintlnAst("Ending $method.name")

            def existingStatements = ((BlockStatement)method.code).statements
            existingStatements.add(0, startMessage)
            existingStatements.add(endMessage)
        }
    }

    private static Statement createPrintlnAst(String message) {
        new ExpressionStatement(
                new MethodCallExpression(
                        new VariableExpression("this"),
                        new ConstantExpression("println"),
                        new ArgumentListExpression(
                                new ConstantExpression(message)
                        )
                )
        )
    }
}
```

A/src/main/resources/META-INF/service/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation

```
gep.WithLoggingASTTransformation
```

B/package1/Application.groovy

```
package package1

class Application {

    def x() {
        println "x"
    }

    static void main(args) {
        println "hi"
        def a = new Application()
        a.x()
    }
}
```

Everything compiles if I run `./gradlew :B:compileGroovy`. However when I run using `./gradlew :B:run` if the AST were applied I would expect to see

> Starting main
>
> starting println
>
> hi
>
> ending println
>
> starting x
>
> starting println
>
> x
>
> ending println
>
> ending x
>
> ending main

However, instead I see:

> hi
>
> x

which leads me to believe the global AST is not being applied. How can I adjust my multi-project build so that a global AST defined in project 'A' is successfully applied to classes in project 'B'?

### Update 1

I was able to apply the global AST by

1. packaging project A as a JAR using `./gradlew :A:jar`
2. change to B directory `cd B`
3. compiling project B using `groovyc -cp A.jar:src/main/groovy/package1/ src/main/groovy/package1/Application.groovy`
4. Running the compiled class using `java -cp groovy-4.0.13.jar:A.jar:. package1.Application`

I also modified package1.Application to better match the example from groovy-lang.org:

B/package1/Application.groovy

```
package package1

def x() {
    println "x"
}

x()
```

With these changes the global AST is applied, but I am still struggling to get it to work inside of a multi-project build.

Comment: Try changing `B/package1/Application.groovy` to just the contents shown here https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#transforms-global (no wrapping class or main method)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @tim_yates, I see how the original Application.groovy might not be transformed by the AST since the source-unit doesn't have top-level methods. I tried making the modification you suggested, but it still doesn't apply the AST during `./gradlew compileGroovy`.  I was able to get it to work by using `groovyc`, but I'm still struggling with getting gradle to apply the AST.

Answer (score 1):

Things appear to be simpler than my googling had suggested. The main things that needed to be changed were:

1. replace references to `astTransformation` configuration with `implementation`, and delete the block configuring GroovyCompile AST classpath

B/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'application'
}

mainClassName = 'project1.App'

dependencies {
    implementation platform('org.apache.groovy:groovy-bom:4.0.5')
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy'
    implementation project(':A')
}
```

2. Apply the AST to the same code used in the example (no wrapping class/main method):

```
package package1

def x() {
    println "x"
}

x()
```

The reason 2. is needed is because the AST transformation defined by WithLoggingASTTransformation is applied to `sourceUnit.AST.methods` which references top-level methods, not those within a class.

With these changes `./gradlew :B:run` produces transformed output:

> Starting x
>
> x
>
> Ending x